# subclasses of CALayer produce EXC_BAD_ACCESS when animating, but direct instances don't?

Tags: ios, ios5, core-animation, calayer, exc-bad-access

In a `touchesMoved` event handler... why does this break:

```
CALayer *slayer = (CALayer*)[[self.layer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0];
slayer.position=CGPointMake(x,y);
```

but this works fine:

```
CALayer *slayer = (CALayer*)[[self.layer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0];

[CATransaction begin]; // temporarily disable layer animations
[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue  forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
slayer.position=CGPointMake(x,y);
[CATransaction commit];
```

for a subclass of `CALayer`, but both seem to work for an instance of class `CALayer` itself?

More detail...

Frustratingly, the app ran just fine under iOS 4.3, and now the same code is generating `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when I attempt to animate its parameters.

I understand that `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is generated when you send a message to an object that has been deleted, so in trying to fix this issue, I've taken care to ensure that all layers are retained, and stored in a cache, so they'll remain around until I clear the cache.  I also check the retain count of the layer in question and it is `3`, at the time of the call that is breaking things, so it seems to be a valid layer.  I have tried running with `NSZombieEnabled`, but it produces the same results, and no different error messages.

Is there something I'm missing?  Did something change between iOS4.3 and iOS5?  What is causing my supposedly ok layer, to crash Core Animation?

---

*fwiw: I am using Xcode 4.2, on a June 2009, Macbook Pro.*

Comment: for what it is worth, I have had to work around this issue by using layer delegates to do my custom draw behaviors.  This seems to work.

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for the idea.  No I hadn't tried that.  In the end I massively recoded as a workaround, and so am just using stock CALayers now.  I'm still confused as to why what I was doing wasn't working, but no longer have code around to test the issue.

Comment: As a note, `-retainCount`is a useless function - it does not output what you would expect and is usually more of a hinderance in debugging.